# Can someone who does not consider himself a US citizen be extradited and punished for a US felony crime due to a US citizenship?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

based off of the answer to this question: [If one leaves the US to commit an act illegal in the US but legal in the country they travel to are they guilty of a crime?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/if-one-leaves-the-us-to-commit-an-act-illegal-in-the-us-but-legal-in-the-country/4631#4631)  My first bizarre loophole question has to do with situations when someone is a US citizen, but consider themselves to be citizens of a different country with different laws..

Lets say you have two Individuals Bob, age 17, and Alice, who just turned 18, who live in, and are citizens of, some non-US country X, who are dating and have a sexual relationship.  Say country X considers the age of consent 16, recognizes dual citizenship, and has an extradition treaty with the US...

However, Alice happened to have been born on a cruise while the cruise ship was sailing through US territorial waters, thus making her a US citizen.  She has never done any of the things which can cause someone to officially lose their US citizenship.

Federal law states [it is illegal for a US citizen to have sex with an individual under the age of 18 in a 'foreign place'](http://trac.syr.edu/laws/18/18USC02423.html)

I'm wondering what, of any of these scenarios, would be illegal due to the above law and could theoretically lead to either extrication, or to arrest when/if they ever visited the US at some later date (and if one is possible but not the later).

1. Alice never realizing she was born actually born in US waters and never thinking of herself as a US citizen, and she never visited the US or engaged in any of the activities that cause her to lose citizenship

   If the above would not be sufficient would any of the below situations potentially lead to prosecution:

   - Knew she was also a US citizen and had once claimed some minor right or privileged due to being a US citizen.
   - Occasionally visits a friend or relative within the US for brief periods, using her US citizenship to allow easier entry to the US, without going through the steps of the VWP.
   - Once stayed in the US with said friend/relative for slightly more then 90 days (beyond the length a regular tourist can stay) many years ago
   - Had just spent spent 91 day summer vacation with her family relative before returning to her home country and having sexual relations with Bob.
2. Alice and Bob both live in and were citizens of X but originally met when both were on a vacation to the US, ultimately having a sexual relationship in their home country.

   Would Alice potentially face prosecution, if not would this change if:

   - The couple had (legally) engaged in sexual activity in the US prior to traveling back home
   - The couple originally met in a state where sexual intercourse would have been illegal and so waited until returning home before having a sexual relationship?
   - Alice bought bob plan ticket home, so she is officially 'transporting' bob? (section a of the above law applies)
   - Alice and bob did have a relationship prior to their visit to the US which continued during their US visit.

I realize that prosecutor discretion would usually result in no one choosing to prosecutor most if not all of the above cases, despite any  legal right, but I'm asking rather they could face charges if a prosecutor did choose to move forward for some reason.  I don't know why they would, maybe they are angry at Alice for some other legal act and this is their way of bending the laws to punish Alice in some way, maybe someone is putting pressure on Alice as some political maneuver to pressure her important father into something, maybe some prosecutor is just really gung-ho in prosecuting crimes for some reason whatever...

*Edit:
Looking back at the law I linked I realized that the definition of illicit sexual encounter, when outside of US territories, is effectively defined as a commercial sexual act, which negates all my examples since no one was being payed.  However, I'm not interested in the specific law so much as how any law making activities on foreign territory illegal would be applied to citizens, and only used this law because it was the only one I knew of to reliable reference.  For now umm...just pretend that illicit sexual act part of the law was not limited only to commercial acts when answering this question?  I think the heart of what I'm trying to understand wouldn't change if that law were slightly different and that's easier then my rewriting all of the above.

ps. A US citizen can travel to Angola and have sex with a 12 year old without any repercussion so long as he doesn't pay anyone if I'm reading the law right?  That's something I really didn't need to know about.  I knew I shouldn't have used that particular law as my example for this...

pps. Also the definition of "any person can be charged with a
    criminal offense" seems extremely vague since it doesn't specify what country/state laws would apply for deciding if the person could be charged with a criminal offense, and I'm sure if you look far enough countries have outlawed all kind of things as sexual offenses, like being in the presence of a women who isn't wearing a hijab.

Comment: Ugh.  I usually love editing posts, but this one just needs to be rewritten, starting with the title!

Comment: Note: A lot of states will not extradite their citizens. If you have dual citizenship and are living in the country of your other citizenship, you may well be safe from extradition as long as you're in said country.

Comment: Note 2: Your reading of "illicit sex act" is not correct. 18 USC 2423(f)(1) says it includes acts with someone under 18 which *would* be illegal under chapter 109A if they *were* committed in special maritime and territorial jurisdiction. Per 18 USC 2241(c), this includes sex with anyone under 16 who is at least 4 years younger than you, and anyone under 12 period.

Comment: Doesn't citizenship need to be claimed? So Alice in situation 1 wouldn't even be a US citizen,right?

Comment: @YviDe: No. Citizenship and nationality are purely matters of law. Who is a citizen and national of each country are solely determined by the laws of that country. It's not up to anyone to "claim" or "not claim" except as provided by the country's law.

Comment: @cpast: Most countries will not extradite anyone for something that isn't a crime in the country that is supposed to do the extraditing.

Comment: Contrary to popular opinion, being born in US territory does not automatically make you a U.S. citizen.

Comment: @derTruth Correct.  For being born in a US territory to make someone a US citizen, the person's parents have to be in the US without enjoying diplomatic immunity.  For everyone else, being born in US territory makes them a US citizen.

Comment: @phoog I was vaguely aware of the above criteria, but this is an edge-case right?  Your saying that 95% or more of cases just happening to be burn in any situation that qualifies one US territory, like being in their territorial waters or on a boat registered within the US even if it's off your home country coast, would make one a defacto US citizen without any other action taken right?  barring any other edge case situations for diplomatic issues, like being in an embassy etc.

Comment: @dsollen yes.  The overwhelming majority of those born in the US (probably more like 99.9% or more) are automatically US citizens, regardless of their parents' legal status.  That's why there is controversy about "anchor babies," "birth tourism," and other issues related to birthright citizenship.  I don't think a US ship in foreign territorial waters would count, but I don't really know.

Comment: Side note: if Alice turns 18 and has not claimed her US Citizenship, it's forfeited. I have a friend who is going through this because his parents, despite getting it for all his brothers and sisters, neglected to get his. They told him once you're 18 there's nothing they can do. He has to apply for a Green Card now.

Comment: @corsiKa Is Alice required to claim her citizenship by 18 because she was "born on a cruise while the cruise ship was sailing through US territorial waters"?  If not, what is her claim to citizenship?  I am unfamiliar with any law that requires citizenship to be claimed by age 18.  Who told your friend that "once you're 18 there's nothing they can do"?

Comment: @phoog Straight from their website: https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/citizenship-through-parents it reads in the *opening sentence* "There are two general ways to obtain citizenship through U.S. citizen parents, one at birth and one after birth but before the age of 18." So one of them is as soon as you're born, you can claim the citizenship. If you wait, you have until you're 18.

Comment: @corsiKa not quite. It depends on whether the child meets the criteria in the first table. For example, if you're born outside the US and both your parents are US citizens at the time if your birth and one of them previously resided in the US, then you are a US citizen from birth even if you don't claim the citizenship until after you're 18.

Comment: @phoog There may be some corner cases that allow someone to get citizenship after their 18th birthday, Much like your comment to dsollen above, coming up with like edge cases for the sake of proving someone wrong doesn't help. Bottom line is if you want your citizenship without question, get it done while you're still under 18. Even if you technically have a right to it after that, it will be much easier to do so before.

Comment: Props to Alice's mother for whatever "lean in"-style thinking led her to go on a cruise with a baby about to pop.

Comment: @corsiKa: The people who must claim citizenship by 18 are those born OUTSIDE the US, claiming citizenship because one or both parents were citizens. People born INSIDE the US are citizens forever, absent one of the very few acts that cause forfeiture of US citizenship.

Comment: @DavidSiegel only *certain people* born outside the US must claim US citizenship before turning 18.  There's no deadline for those falling under §301 (subsection c, d, or g, or certainly h, which affects only people who were over 60 years old when it was enacted).  The 18-year deadline applies to §320 and $322, and §320 requires moving to the US, not submitting an application.

Comment: @corsiKa One person's corner case is another's common case. You may have a friend who apparently could have fallen under INA §322 and failed to act before turning 18, but I know several people who were born abroad to US citizen parents and acquired US citizenship under INA §301, for which there is no deadline. I have also read about several cases of adults who acquired citizenship under INA §320 without knowing it and learned of that acquisition in removal proceedings from their lawyers who saved them from removal even though they never had any citizenship documentation before turning 18.

Comment: Important to note that very, very few U.S. law criminal offenses have U.S. citizenship as an element of the office and extend to the extraterritorial conduct, and that this is similarly true in most other countries. I doubt that there are twenty such offenses in U.S. law, and there are probably fewer. Most laws either apply to U.S. situ conduct only, or apply extraterritorially without regard to citizenship.

Comment: @ohwilleke "U.S. situ" including "special maritime and territorial jurisdiction"?  Also, 18 USC 2423 has a couple of sections that apply to US citizens and LPRs.  Would you count that as "having US citizenship as an element" or "without regard to citizenship"?  (And would a  noncitizen national be likely to prevail with an argument that it doesn't apply to noncitizen nationals?)

Comment: Can we at some point change the title, since whether you _consider_ yourself a US citizen or not is quite irrelevant to anything. Whether the USA considers you a US citizen, or maybe some other country, that is what counts.

Comment: @gnasher729 this has been bothering me too.  If the question is about someone who isn't _aware_ of her US citizenship, as suggested by the example, the title should say that instead.  If the question is truly about someone who doesn't "consider" herself a US citizen then the answer is simply "what anyone considers her US citizenship status to be is irrelevant."  In other words, the question as it stands now is unclear as to whether it concerns citizenship law or extradition and extraterritoriality of criminal law.

Comment: @gnasher729 On the other hand, the question is almost 8 years old and has generated a lot of responses, so changing it may be a bad idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### [Ignorantia juris non excusat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignorantia_juris_non_excusat)

You can say I didn't know: it won't keep you out of jail.

Rather than delving into the specifics of your question, I will keep my answer general. If you break the law, you break the law. It doesn't matter if:

- you don't know what the law is,
- you didn't think the law applied to you,
- you thought what you were doing was in accordance with the law.

**"Break the law"** is an objective fact - there is no subjectivity involved. The state of mind of the person is, in most jurisdictions, irrelevant; the common law doctrine of *mens rea* or "the guilty mind" has almost universally been done away with.

Now specific offences have specific defences. Generally, in underage sex cases genuine ignorance of the age of the person is one such defence. A court may decide that ignorance that the person was underage *under US law* may qualify for this defence.

Comment: Sorry to necrocomment, but I am not entirely sure if ignorantia juris non excusat fully applies here. If Alice did not know she was a US citizen at all this would appear to be a mistake of fact as opposed to ignorance of law?

Comment: Following on to Vality, we could specify that while Alice's citizenship is a combined matter of fact and law, if she were genuinely under the impression that the ship was in international waters at the time of her birth, and she was unaware of any other fact that would result in her being a US citizen, then it would be purely a case of ignorance of the facts.

Comment: I thought Mens Rea was enshrined in law as the basis for law...

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser mens rea is a common law doctrine - in almost all common law jurisdictions crimes are codified not common law crimes. In almost all jurisdictions some crimes require it but most don’t.

Comment: @DaleM One of the *original* common law jurisdictions (England and Wales) has not been fully codified - murder is still a common law offence.  I believe *Mens rea* applies to codified laws too.

Comment: Isn’t *intent* still an element of many crimes?

Comment: Sorry, but "break the law" is almost always a subjective fact. Otherwise there would be no need for judges and juries. Not only are the facts themselves subject to subjective discretion (what can you actually prove happened?), but the limits of what's legal or not are often subjective. And because laws have intent, you can almost always find a place where the letter and intent differ, bringing in more subjective interpretations. Whether you were found guilty or not is the only truly objective thing here.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite: Yes, many laws I've read in the past couple decades have intent as a clear bit of criteria for guilt. The distinction here is intent to perform an action (which happened to be illegal) vs intent to break the law you didn't know about. Typically, having reasonable cause to think you were following the law helps your defense, but I've had judges find me guilty of traffic infractions after a preceding judge found me guilty for doing what the second judge insisted was the law, so even case law doesn't always help you out.

Comment: @MichaelS I fundamentally disagree. The role of the judge is to determine what the law is and the role of the jury is to *determine* what the facts are and how the law applies to them. Just because it might be difficult to determine what the facts are, that doesn’t make them “subjective”.

Comment: @DaleM: That's pretty much the definition of "subjective". The judge has to figure out how the law applies to this exact scenario (no law covers all of them) and the jury has to figure out what the "real truth" is, which is impossible.

Comment: We might relax my "almost always" if we want to define it as "objective" when the judge looks at the facts and doesn't even quibble about where it falls into the law. But at a fundamental level it's rarely objective.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser "Mens Rea" is not about knowing intent to break the law, but about intent to do whatever you did.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Indeed, intent is the *major* requirement in cases of attempt, for example in cases of impossibility. E.g. somebody tries to rape or kill a dead person: Obviously not a crime *per se*, but we really don't like the attitude.

Answer (score 6):

One line for Alice to pursue, is that *in general* a country will not extradite someone (even a citizen of the country requesting extradition) on charges that are not a crime in that country. Country X won't hold a full criminal trial to establish this, but they will have some standard (which varies according to what extradition treaties they have with the US) that extradition charges must meet in order to be considered.

irth's answer contains a case that may or may not be an exception to this rule (I don't know whether it was ruled that he would be extradited despite nothing having been done that Canada considers an offence, or whether Canada found a way to construe what he was charged with as being an offence). But even if the general principle doesn't always hold in Canada and didn't help that person, it may still be relevant to Country X and to Alice.

So, if the act *is* a crime in country X then since it occurred in country X on the whole X won't extradite because they will instead prosecute. And if the act is *not* a crime in country X then Alice may hope that X declines to extradite. **This depends entirely on the law of country X** (well, plus I suppose any diplomacy the US might bring to bear against X to "encourage" a particular verdict). Firstly they must refuse to extradite such cases, and secondly they must determine that Alice's US citizenship does *not* alter the relevant age of consent for her. Even if she wins, it's still not an ideal outcome for Alice. She may find herself unable to visit any countries in which her act *would be* a crime, for fear that unlike X they would indeed arrest and extradite her to the US.

So for example, suppose the US were to make it a crime for any US citizen to reside abroad (never mind whether that's constitutional: let's just say the US changes the constitution too if necessary!). Then one would *not* expect every country of the world to arrest and extradite all US citizens resident in that country, and *especially* not to do so for their own nationals who are US dual citizens. I've exaggerated the situation to something that quite clearly other countries do not considers a crime, just to remove any doubt that country X would consider the charges in the extradition request to be non-crimes.

Comment: Country Y will say "please extradite Alice because she did ...", and country X has to just check whether what Alice is accused of would be prosecuted in X. That would just involve looking up some law books.

Answer (score 4):

A perhaps better example of the general principle. It is illegal under US law for US citizens to engage in commercial bribery in a non-US country, even if such acts are not illegal under local law. (I believe that the UK has a similar law.) The country where the bribery took place might or might not extradite a person charged with such an act, but many other countries surely would, and if such a person were to visit the US s/he could surely be arrested.

This avoids the complications of laws about sexual acts.

Answer (score 1):

As cpast already pointed out in the comments, it would not actually be illegal under US law for an 18 year old US citizen to have sex with a 17 year old in a country whose local law permits such sexual relationships. Bob would need to be under the age of 12, or Bob would need to be under the age of 16 with Alice being at least 4 years older than Bob, in order for the US law in question to apply.

If Alice were 20 and Bob were 15, then it would be illegal under US law for Alice, being a US citizen, to have sex with Bob while outside the US.

I'll address the issue of extradition momentarily. If Alice is in the US and is prosecuted by the US for the offence, Alice can *probably* use the fact that she didn't know she was a US citizen as a defense against 18 USC §2423(c). In [*Kawakita v. United States*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawakita_v._United_States) (1952), the government was required to prove that Kawakita knew he was still a US national at the time when he committed the alleged acts, because only US nationals can commit treason against the US. [*Rehaif v. United States*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rehaif_v._United_States) (2019) concerned a law where one of the elements of the offense is *not* being a US national, and in fact not having a lawful status in the US. In that case, the Supreme Court held that the government must prove that Rehaif knew that he didn't have a lawful status.

*However,* the government could argue in the case of Alice that having US citizenship or lawful permanent resident status is a *jurisdictional element* of an offense under §2423(c) rather than a *material element*, thus distinguishing Alice's case from *Kawakita* and *Rehaif*. The prosecution is not required to prove that the defendant had knowledge of a jurisdictional element. For example, if you're smoking marijuana while strolling through a forest in Canada, and you happen to step into the United States without knowing that you've stepped into the United States, you can be convicted under US law despite the fact that you didn't know you were in the US. So, if US citizenship is held to be a jurisdictional element in §2423(c), Alice could be convicted without the government needing to prove that she knew she was a US citizen. (To be honest, I'm not sure how to tell whether it's a jurisdictional or material element. I'm not a lawyer and I've never been to law school. I imagine this is one of those things they teach people in law school, only for most students to forget shortly after passing the bar exam.)

Regarding extradition:

#### If the act is legal under local law

Extradition is generally not required in cases where the act upon which the extradition request is based is legal under local law (the so-called [*dual criminality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_criminality) doctrine). However, some countries' laws do *permit* (not *require*) the authorities, at their discretion, to extradite people for acts that are legal under local law.

#### If the act is illegal under local law

Alice will generally be tried and punished under the law of the country where the offence occurred. Extradition treaties and domestic extradition laws usually don't require extradition in such circumstances, *i.e.*, the country where the offence occurred is not required to extradite Alice for the purposes of having her tried and punished a second time in the requesting country. Again, some countries probably *permit* (but do not *require*) the authorities to approve a request to extradite someone out of the country under such circumstances.